# Как парсить html файлы, а не сайты? Jsoup

Tags: java, парсер, jsoup

У меня есть каталог скаченный Html-файлов, хочу потренироваться в их парсинге, но не могу понять, как мне при помощи jsoup найти эти файлы ( в каталоге html файлы разбросаны по папкам ) для дальнейшего парсинга?
Данный код выдаёт ошибку, не понимаю, как правильно указать путь ( в идеале нужно все html файлы в каталоге) .

```
import org.jsoup.*;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ParsingGcTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Document document=Jsoup.connect("C:\\Users\\71376160\\Desktop\\docs\\specs\\security\\standard-names.html").get();
        Elements elements=document.select("code");
        for(Element element: elements){
            System.out.println(element);
        }
    }
}
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed URL: C:\Users\71376160\Desktop\docs\specs\security\standard-names.html
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.url(HttpConnection.java:131)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:70)
    at org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect(Jsoup.java:73)
    at ParsingGcTest.main(ParsingGcTest.java:10)
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:679)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:568)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:515)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.url(HttpConnection.java:129)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: Было бы не плохо текст ошибки скопировать

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [edit])

Comment: @gil9red спасибо, исправил

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Причина ошибки в том, что `connect` ожидал ссылку на сайт (поэтому он за протокол принял `C`, т.к. например между `C:` и `http:` есть схожесть :) )

Попробуйте через [parse загрузить файл](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-file):

```
String filename = "C:\\Users\\71376160\\Desktop\\docs\\specs\\security\\standard-names.html";
File input = new File(filename);
Document document = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "http://example.com/");
...
```

Третий параметр в `parse` это `baseUri`, оно нужно для определения полных адресов для относительных ссылок в документе. Если это не нужно, то можно оставить пустую строку.

Comment: Написал вот так
`Document document=Jsoup.parse("C:\\Users\\71376160\\Desktop\\docs\\specs\\security\\standard-names.html","");
 Elements elements=document.select("code");`
но выдаёт пустоту, хотя из <code> состоит весь html файл

Comment: Попробовал вывести все элементы, почему то не пишет, что содержится в body, вместо этого там путь на файл